# How to do multiple conditions for single If statement

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to do two conditions on a single If statement in vbscript.  Should be really simple, but it's not working.  Something like:

```
 If Not (fileName = testFileName) & (fileName <> "") Then
Else ....
```

I'm making it two if statements to get it working, but can I do a not conditional with an "and" with another not condition?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the 'And' keyword for a logical and.  Like this:

```
If Not ((filename = testFileName) And (fileName <> "")) Then
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was trying to do!  Actually, the Not keyword doesn't work.  This does:  If ((fileName <> objErrFileName) And (fileName <> "")) Then

Comment: @Hogan: whoops, with that added set of parentheses, you changed the logic!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I think it's to control operator precedence

Comment: @adampski: So do I, but who knows whether the OP didn't want it the other way around?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett True, hopefully now whoever reads this in future knows the purpose of extra parathese and can decide with that in mind

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - Just to be clear -- I changed to logic to what was clearly the OP's intention "if file is not empty and does not equal testFileName"  The other possible meaning ("file is not empty and equals testFileName") would make no sense since that is the same as "equals testFileName".

Answer (score 9):

As Hogan notes above, use an `AND` instead of `&`. See this [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptoperators.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the codes to check multiple IF in VBS:**

```
Function isFlagTrue(line)
    ' wscript.echo "line : "& line
    Dim returnValue, key, value, result
    key = "SHOULD_SEND_EMAIL"
    value="TRUE"
    If InStr(line, key) > 0 And InStr(line, value) > 0 Then
        returnValue = True
    Else
        returnValue = False
    End If
    ' wscript.echo "HELLO : "& returnValue
    isFlagTrue = returnValue
End Function
```