# can I add condition to the statement for if

Tags: vbscript

I need some help on below script I am doing a auto delete based on file extension and date modified.

I just started on vbscript so not really sure about how it worked.

I will want it to delete older file based on date and file extension when the first condition is true and if the condition is false it will end

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objSTR, objTYP, objFILE`enter code here`
Dim Folder, SubFolder

Dim objNetwork, strRemoteshare, strUser, strPassword
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strRemoteShare = "shared drive path"
strUser = "user"
strPassword = "password"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "X:", strRemoteshare, True, strUser, 
strPassword
objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "X:", True , True 

objTYP = "file extension"
For Each objFILE In objFSO.GetFolder("folder path").Files
If objFile.Type = objTYP And objFILE.DateLastModified < 
DateAdd("d",-5,Now) = True Then
'in the statement here i want it delete the older file based on  
'objFile.Type = objTYP And objFILE.DateLastModified > DateAdd("d",-10,Now)
ElseIf objFile.Type = objTYP And objFILE.DateLastModified < 
DateAdd("d",-5,Now) = False Then
End If
Next
```

Comment: Probably, but your code is unindented and includes many lines that do nothing.

Comment: `If` statement conditions need to evaluate to `True`. In your `If` the condition `objFILE.DateLastModified < 
DateAdd("d",-5,Now) = True` makes no sense try just `objFILE.DateLastModified < 
DateAdd("d",-5,Now)` instead which will evaluate to `True` if the `DateLastModified` is less then five days from todays date and time. You can then remove the `ElseIf` line completely and replace it with just `Else` which will evaluate the `False` outcome.

Comment: I am doing this for backup and I will want it to delete older backup after it detect that new backup have been done. so if I put condition as `objFILE.DateLastModified <  DateAdd("d",-5,Now)` is `True` and I want the statement to delete files that are more then 7 days from todays date and time. what will I need to put? thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kaijie you would need to change the `-5` to `-7` in the `DateAdd()`  as that represents the previous number of days to compare against today's date. Then you would want to call the [`Delete()` method of the `File` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0k4wket3(v=vs.84)) which you have assigned to `objFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the comments in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309822/can-i-add-condition-to-the-statement-for-if/66313669#comment117236585_66309822) you need to first fix the evaluation and then add the call to [`File` object `Delete()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0k4wket3(v=vs.84)).

```vb
For Each objFILE In objFSO.GetFolder("folder path").Files
  If objFILE.Type = objTYP And objFILE.DateLastModified < DateAdd("d", -7, Now()) Then
    'File older than 7 days will be removed.
    Call objFILE.Delete(True) 'Pass true to force deletion.
  End If
Next
```

#### Useful Links

- [How to do multiple conditions for single If statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489861/692942)

Comment: The file that I want to detect and delete is Veeam full backup file. I tried the command and is unable to delete I change it and it is able to delete TXT file but not the backup. the folder path is in a shared drive does it matter? so sorry about the command not really sure how to do it.
    `For Each objFILE In objFSO.GetFolder("Folder path").Files`
   `If objFILE.DateLastModified < DateAdd("d", -7, Now()) Then`
     `'File older than 7 days will be removed.`
    `Call objFILE.Delete(True) 'Pass true to force deletion.`
    `End If`
    `Next`

Comment: You may need to call the script with elevated permissions. You may also need to check the permissions assigned to the shared drive, do you get a specific error when try the script?

Comment: Before that I was using batch file and it is able to delete the file but unable to detect is there new backup. I am using vbsedit to run it and I get no error
 ***** script completed - exit code: 0 *****

Comment: If I remove `objFILE.Type = objTYP` and add in `WScript.Echo "check"` I will have a output but when I add in it doesn't show. I think that the problem might be the file extension as the file extension is .vbk which is also a audio file extension. for the `objTYP = "file extension"` i put the full name of the extension not sure it will work

Comment: @Kaijie sounds like the issue is with your code, I can only provide an answer based on the information available to me which has been provided by you. If the `objTYP` variable isn't doing what you expect that has no bearing on the initial problem of your evaluation being incorrect, which this answer has covered.